# Show $\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)(x-x_0) =0$ when $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}^+$ & monotone increasing.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show $\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)(x-x_0) =0$ when $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}^+$ & monotone increasing.

---

**Try**

I need to show,

$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0 : x \in (x_0, x_0 + \delta) \Rightarrow |f(x) (x-x_0)| < \epsilon
$$

I think I could find some upper bound $M >0$ such that $|f(x) (x-x_0)| \le M |x - x_0|$.

Let $M = f(x_0 + \epsilon)$, and let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\max \{2M, 2 \}}$, then clearly $f(x) \le f(x_0 + \epsilon) = M$

But I'm not sure $|f(x) (x-x_0)| \le M |x - x_0|$.

Any hint about how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
|f(x)(x-x_0)|\leq |f(x_0)||x-x_0|
\end{align}
for all $x\leq x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $M=f(x_0+1)$ and cosider $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2M}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Let $M=f(x_0+1)$ and choose $\delta=\mathrm{min}\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\}$. For each $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)$, $|f(x)|\leq M$ since $f$ is strictly increasing. Thus, $|f(x)(x-x_0)|\leq M|x-x_0|<M\delta\leq\varepsilon$.